# Canvas arc on Retina is too sharp at some points

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create animated arc that doesn't look blurry on HiDPI devices.

This is how my arc looks on iPhone 5s:

[image: canvas arc]

you can see that near 0, 90, 180 deg arc becomes too sharp. How can I prevent this?

This is my code:

```js
// Canvas arc progress
const can = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = can.getContext('2d');
const circ = Math.PI * 2;
const quart = Math.PI / 2;
const canvasSize = can.offsetWidth;
const halfCanvasSize = canvasSize / 2;

let start = 0,
  finish = 70,
  animRequestId = null;

// Get pixel ratio
const ratio = (function() {
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
})();

// Set canvas h & w
can.width = can.height = canvasSize * ratio;
can.style.width = can.style.height = canvasSize + 'px';
ctx.scale(ratio, ratio)

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(120,159,194)';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.lineWidth = 8.0;
ctx.arc(halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize - 4, 0, circ, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(244,247,255)';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 8.0;
ctx.closePath();

let imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize);

const draw = (current) => {
  ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize - 4, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
  ctx.stroke();
};

(function animateArcProgress() {
  animRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(animateArcProgress);

  if (start <= finish) {
    draw(start / 100);
    start += 2;
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animRequestId);
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  widht: 300px;
  background: #85b1d7;
}
canvas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can soften the edge by drawing 1/2 pixel inside as done in your code below.

I rendered the arc 3 times at 8, 7.5 and 7 pixel width width alpha colour values 0.25, 0.5 and 1 respectively.

You can make it as soft as you want.

BTW using putImageData is very slow, why not just render the background to another canvas and draw that via ctx.drawImage(offScreencanvas,0,0) that way you will use the GPU to render the background rather than the CPU via the graphics port bus.

I added a bit more code to show the different softening FX you can get and added a mouse zoom so you can see the pixels a little better.

```js
const can = document.getElementById('canvas');
const can2 = document.createElement("canvas"); // off screen canvas 
const can3 = document.createElement("canvas"); // off screen canvas 

const ctx = can.getContext('2d');
const ctx2 = can2.getContext('2d');
const ctx3 = can3.getContext('2d');
const circ = Math.PI * 2;
const quart = Math.PI / 2;
const canvasSize = can.offsetWidth;
const halfCanvasSize = canvasSize / 2;
const mouse = {x : null, y : null};
can.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    var bounds = can.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    mouse.y = e.clientY - bounds.top;        
});
let start = 0,
  finish = 70,
  animRequestId = null;

// Get pixel ratio
const ratio = (function() {
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
})();

// Set canvas h & w
can2.height = can3.height = can2.width = can3.width = can.width = can.height = canvasSize * ratio;
can.style.width = can.style.height = canvasSize + 'px';

ctx.scale(ratio, ratio)
ctx2.scale(ratio, ratio)
ctx3.scale(ratio, ratio)

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.strokeStyle = 'rgb(120,159,194)';
ctx2.lineCap = 'square';
ctx2.lineWidth = 8.0;
ctx2.arc(halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize - 4, 0, circ, false);
ctx2.stroke();
ctx2.closePath();

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.strokeStyle = 'rgb(244,247,255)';
ctx2.lineCap = 'round';
ctx2.lineWidth = 8.0;
ctx2.closePath();


const draw = (current) => {
  ctx3.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx3.drawImage(can2,0,0);
  var rad = halfCanvasSize - 4;
  const drawArc = () => {
      ctx3.beginPath();
      ctx3.arc(halfCanvasSize, halfCanvasSize, rad, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
      ctx3.stroke();          
  }
  // draw soft
  ctx3.strokeStyle = 'rgb(244,247,255)';
  ctx3.lineWidth = 8.5;
  ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.25;
  drawArc();;

  ctx3.lineWidth = 7.0;
  ctx3.globalAlpha  = 0.5;
  drawArc();;

  ctx3.lineWidth = 6.5;
  ctx3.globalAlpha  = 1;
  drawArc();

  // draw normal
  rad -= 12;
  ctx3.lineWidth = 8.0;
  ctx3.globalAlpha = 1;
  drawArc();;


  
  // draw ultra soft
  rad -= 12;
  ctx3.strokeStyle = 'rgb(244,247,255)';
  ctx3.lineWidth = 9.0;
  ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  drawArc();

  ctx3.lineWidth = 8.0;
  ctx3.globalAlpha  = 0.2;
  drawArc();;

  ctx3.lineWidth = 7.5;
  ctx3.globalAlpha  = 0.5;
  drawArc();

  ctx3.lineWidth = 6;
  ctx3.globalAlpha  = 1;
  drawArc();




};

const zoomW = 30;
const zoomAmount = 5;
const drawZoom = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(can3,0,0);
    var width = zoomW * zoomAmount;
    var cx = mouse.x -  width / 2;
    var cy = mouse.y -  width / 2;
    var c1x = mouse.x -  zoomW / 2;
    var c1y = mouse.y -  zoomW / 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(244,247,255)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeRect(cx,cy,width,width);
    ctx.clearRect(cx,cy,width,width);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.drawImage(can3,c1x,c1y,zoomW,zoomW,cx,cy,width,width);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
}
function keepUpdating(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
    drawZoom();
    requestAnimationFrame(keepUpdating);
}

(function animateArcProgress() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);

  draw(start / 100);
  drawZoom();
  
  
  if (start <= finish) {
    start += 0.5;
    requestAnimationFrame(animateArcProgress);
  } else {
    requestAnimationFrame(keepUpdating);  
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  widht: 300px;
  background: #85b1d7;
}
canvas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort!! I used your idea and successfully made arc look like it is 'antialiased'! Thanks that you mentioned that `putImageData` is slow. Instead of this I now use div with a border.